# How to make a large icon appear in Firefox's new tab Top Sites?

Tags: firefox, favicon

In the latest stable release of Firefox (version 57), dubbed Quantum, the user controlled Top Sites feature on new tabs changed.  Previously, only a crude thumbnail of a partial screenshot appeared regardless of website and could not be controlled.  Now some websites appear with a large icon while others only show as the aforementioned thumbnail and their favicon overlaid in the corner.  Example sites that get the large icon treatment:  Amazon, TechCrunch, Slack, and GitHub.  Example sites that get the thumbnail with favicon treatment:   Slashdot, Steam, Kongregate, Gizmodo.

As far as I can tell, there isn't any particular rhyme or reason to this.  I also haven't found any documentation anywhere on the Top Sites feature.

---

After digging into the Firefox source code for a while, I found `browser\extensions\activity-stream\lib\TopSitesFeed.jsm`, which has this section of code:

```
/**
 * Get an image for the link preferring tippy top, rich favicon, screenshots.
 */
async _fetchIcon(link) {
  // Check for tippy top icon and rich icon.
  this._tippyTopProvider.processSite(link);
  let hasTippyTop = !!link.tippyTopIcon;
  let hasRichIcon = link.favicon && link.faviconSize >= MIN_FAVICON_SIZE;

  if (!hasTippyTop && !hasRichIcon) {
    this._requestRichIcon(link.url);
  }

  // Request a screenshot if needed.
  if (!hasTippyTop && !hasRichIcon && !link.screenshot) {
    const {url} = link;
    await Screenshots.maybeCacheScreenshot(link, url, "screenshot",
      screenshot => this.store.dispatch(ac.BroadcastToContent({
        data: {screenshot, url},
        type: at.SCREENSHOT_UPDATED
      })));
  }
}
```

Earlier, `MIN_FAVICON_SIZE` is defined as 96, which I assume is in pixels.

Looking at `TippyTop`, I see some preferential treatment being made for Amazon, Reddit, Twitter, Facebook, and some other websites (visit `resource://activity-stream/data/content/tippytop/` inside Firefox for the relevant JSON file + images), which I guess means Firefox includes special icons with the final binaries for very specific websites, but not all of the sites I mentioned.

TechCrunch, for example, isn't in the TippyTop list and only has a 16x16 favicon.  However, Firefox shows an icon instead of a screenshot.  There are Apple touch icons on the TechCrunch website that exceed 96 pixels.  So maybe one of those is being used instead.  I generally think of favicons being separate entities from the Apple-specific touch icon meta tags.  This means that webmasters can probably override the screenshot taking mechanism (somehow) and just show a nice icon in the Top Sites list.  So the question still remains as to how to make that happen?  The favicon logic at this point is still somewhat of a mystery.

Comment: This may be the same for Opera's Speed Dial.

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of testing I was able to get large icons working for my website (in Firefox 57.0.4).

I think it is important to use a large (>100px) icon and specify the size:

```
<link rel="icon" type='image/png' sizes='256x256' href="/applogo_256.png"/>
```

In addition Firefox seems to cache the preview quite aggressively, so I needed to use a new Profile to see the change immediately.